# Spring data jpa hibernate one to may duplicate issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have one to many relation ship between a `User` and `UserRole`.

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String username;
private String password;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="userId")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="roleId")}
)
private Collection<UserRole> roles;
}
```

and

```
public class UserRole {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String roleName;
}
```

I am able to save a user at first. But when I try to save another user it rejects with an exception of duplicated entry on the junction table

Comment: Do you try to save the new user with a role that has the same `roleName` as an existing role?

Comment: the strange thing is on my junction table which is `user_roles`, `role_id` is a primary key. how can I remove that

Comment: I expect the combination of `user_id` and `role_id` both will be a primary key but not actually

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is when we have One-to-Many association the many side foreign key will be a primary key on the junction table. So, I need to make the relation Many-to-Many. So that the combination of both foreign keys will serve as a composite key.